# c# wpf 2d animation: Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to Silverlight but you have to start somewhere right?

For my school project I am working on a projectile simulator but I am stuck as to what to do for the 2D animation. when looking at a storyboard most of the examples have very little example for moving the object. Is using a storyboard a good idea for this type of animation or am I doing this completely wrong?

no idea what part of my code to put here so ask and ill edit.

thanks for your help!

Comment: First attempt could be to put the "projectile" element (e.g. an Ellipse) in a Canvas and then animate its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties by two DoubleAnimations in a Storyboard. And if your question is about Silverlight, you should tag it so. WPF and Silverlight are two different frameworks.

Comment: Is it the same school project as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27882028/1136211)?

Comment: yeah its very similar if not the same