# Error:The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. Storyboard simulation

Tags: c#, wpf

For my school project, i am trying a projectile simulation but decided to use a storyboard (not sure if this is the right idea) so there is my code so far. As you can see from the title i get that error when trying to execute
                ellipseStoryboard.Begin(this);
                but i cant see what im doing wrong. Thanks for your help!

My  Code:

```
void onTimedEvent(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs t, particle newProjectile, double TimeInterval, int i, Path myPath, Canvas AnimationCanvas)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        AnimationCanvas.Children.Clear();
    }));

    PointAnimation myPointAnimation = new PointAnimation();
    myPointAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeInterval);
    myPointAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
    myPointAnimation.From = new System.Windows.Point(newProjectile.HDisplacement[i], newProjectile.VDisplacement[i]);
    myPointAnimation.To = new System.Windows.Point(newProjectile.HDisplacement[i + 1], newProjectile.VDisplacement[i + 1]);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myPointAnimation, "MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myPointAnimation, new PropertyPath(EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty));
    Storyboard ellipseStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    ellipseStoryboard.Children.Add(myPointAnimation);
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        myPath.Loaded += delegate(object sender1, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ellipseStoryboard.Begin(this);
        };
    }));
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        AnimationCanvas.Children.Add(myPath);
    }));

}
```

edit: I have calculated the actual displacement points and put them in an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need more than this:

```
myPath.Loaded +=
    (o, e) =>
    {
        var myPointAnimation = new PointAnimation
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeInterval),
            From = new Point(...),
            To = new Point(...)
        };
        MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry.BeginAnimation(
            EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty, myPointAnimation);
    };
```

---

Although an independent animation of the projectile's x and y coordinates (e.g. by two animations in a Storyboard) with a quadratic easing function for the y-coordinate would allow for mocking gravity, you would probably better use [frame-based animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx) for a realistic physical simulation with time-dependent kinematics.

A simple version of the above could look like this:

```
<Path Fill="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="projectileGeometry" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

with the following code-behind, where you have a position, velocity and acceleration of the projectile, and a `Rendering` event handler that calculates the kinematics.

```
private Point position; // in pixels
private Vector velocity; // in pixels per second
private Vector acceleration; // in pixels per square second
private DateTime time;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    position = new Point(100, 100);
    velocity = new Vector(50, -50); // y direction is downwards
    acceleration = new Vector(0, 20); // y direction is downwards
    time = DateTime.Now;
    CompositionTarget.Rendering += OnRendering;
}

private void OnRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t = DateTime.Now;
    var dt = (t - time).TotalSeconds;
    time = t;

    position += velocity * dt;
    velocity += acceleration * dt;

    projectileGeometry.Center = position;

    if (position.Y > ActualHeight)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= OnRendering;
    }
}
```

Comment: im abit confused actually... what im trying to do is to have multiple points to draw to each other as newPointAnimations. Ive now removed it so it no longer uses a timer. But I cant seem to get the animation from linking up to each other

Comment: if I used your code would it replace most of my code?

Comment: And why would the frame-based animation be better than using a storyboard?

Comment: Does that mean you have a pre-calculated set of points used as target of subsequent animations? If so, you might have mentioned that in your question. As I understand your question, you are trying to build a simulation of the kinematics of a projectile. Frame-based animation would be an ideal solution for this, as it provides you with a callback method (the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event) that allows you to calculate the next simulation step based on the current timestamp. It is called as often as possible, but not more often than necessary.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but yeah I have pre-calculated points. but you think it would be better for me to use frame based animation?

Comment: Thank you for your help! <3 I'll change it when I get back home

Comment: how should I call Onloaded? would I use a button or can I manually call the event?

Comment: Forgot to tell that, it's just a handler for the Window's `Loaded` event. It can be set in XAML like `Loaded="OnLoaded"` or in the Window's constructor like `Loaded += OnLoaded;`.

Comment: I have added Loaded += OnLoaded; which is assigned to a button but it doesnt seem to call the OnLoaded event :/ what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add it to the MainWindow, as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! but how do i restrict it to a button?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Do you perhaps mean you want to start the simulation on a button click? Then you should attach a `Click` event handler to that button, instead of a Loaded handler.

Comment: Yeah, ive used btn_TEST.Click += OnLoaded; but still doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to start an animation from a timer.  If you are receiving a threading error, you are probably on the wrong thread.  Instead of marshalling with `Dispatcher.Invoke`, just use a `DispatcherTimer` which will make sure your callbacks are on the UI thread.

Instead of:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += tmrHandler;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

use

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += tmrHandler;
timer.IsEnabled = true;
```